# How my browser extension can periodically refresh file from GitHub rawcontent?

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, cors, service-worker, if-modified-since

In `background.js`, my browser extension periodically fetches a JSON file published in a GitHub public repository.

Now I want it to be nicer to GitHub and its bandwidth limits, and only fetch file again if it was modified since last update:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/pets-data.json';

fetch(url, {
  headers: {'If-Modified-Since': 'Wed, 15 Aug 2022 18:30:00 GMT'}})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log('Loaded: ', json));
```

However **I get CORS error I don't understand how to deal with:**

```
Access to fetch at
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/pets-data.json'
from origin 'chrome-extension://...'
has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Adding either combination of other headers doesn't make difference:

```
 'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'
 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw'
 'User-Agent': 'my_github_username/my_github_repository (Chrome 104.0.5112.79)'
```

Neither does using GitHub Pages as an alternative way to access the file.

---

**Update:** I easily eliminated CORS error adding `raw.githubusercontent.com` to `host_permissions` in `manifest.json` (thanks `@wOxxOm`). However now `If-Modified-Since` doesn't seem to be affect server behavior in the way I expect, see [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379755) with details.

Comment: You need to add `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/` to [host_permissions in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/xhr/#requesting-permission).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, it really helped! Now I don't have that error message, but If-Modified-Since doesn't seem to affect GitHub behavior in any way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379755

Answer (score 4):

Because your request contains an `If-Modified-Since` header, the browser triggers [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). However, the resource, despite responding to `GET` requests with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, doesn't seem to support preflight: if you try to spoof a preflight request, it invariably (according to my tests) replies with a 403 status, which is [sufficient for CORS preflight to fail](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch-0).

The resource does respond with an [`ETag` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag). One approach would consist in sending a [*simple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) `HEAD` request first, read the value of the response's `ETag` header, and conditionally send a `GET` request after that. Unfortunately, because `ETag` is not a [CORS-safelisted response-header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name) and the response doesn't contain any [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers), the browser won't expose the response's `ETag` header to JavaScript. Very sad.

Short of pressuring GitHub into adding support for CORS preflight on `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`, a viable, albeit annoying, alternative would be to proxy your original `GET` request (containing the `If-Modified-Since` header) to a server you control, which would be unconstrained by the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).